$\int \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} \psi d\mathbf{r} > c$, can I find an upper bound on $\int \frac{\psi}{\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}} d\mathbf{r}$?
Let $\psi(\mathbf{r}):\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+ \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\psi d\mathbf{r} =1$.
I know $\int \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} \psi d\mathbf{r} > c$, can I find an upper bound on $\int \frac{\psi}{\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}} d\mathbf{r}$ ?
EDIT As @Pranay notes, a sufficiently singular $\psi$ will not allow upper-bound. In my original problem, $\psi$ is solution to a Fokker-Plank equation, so will be in $L^\infty$.
This evokes Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but I don't seem to find a way to use it for doing bounds this way around.

I don’t think there’s such a bound. Consider, for example, $\psi(\mathbf r) = e^{-|\mathbf r|}/|\mathbf r|^2$.

@Pranay: seems to be integrable over $R^3$ ? But yes, $e^{-|r|}/|r|^4$...

Yes the first two integrals are finite, but the third isn’t.

@Pranay: checking on the original problem, one important bit that was missing is that it can be shown $\psi$ is $L^{\infty}$.

Sure just replace $r^2$ with $r^2+\epsilon$ in the denominator for some small $\epsilon >0$. While the first two integrals are still bounded, the third integral diverges as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. Moreover, this function is bounded, so it is in $L^\infty$

The lower bound $\int \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} \psi d\mathbf{r} > c$ acted as a red herring, it's not useful actually. We split the integral at $|\mathbf{r}|=1$ and use $L^{\infty}$ and the other integral.
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{1}{\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \psi d\mathbf{r} 
 &= \iiint \frac{1}{r^2} \psi \,rd\phi\, r \sin(\theta)d\theta\, dr\\
 &\leq 4\pi\int_{0}^1 \sup_{\phi,\theta}\psi dr + \int_{|\mathbf{r}|>1} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^2}\psi d\mathbf{r} \\
 &< 4\pi\|\psi\|_\infty + \int_{|\mathbf{r}|>1} \psi d\mathbf{r}\\
 &< 4\pi\|\psi\|_\infty + 1
\end{align*}
If $\psi \not\in L^\infty$, @Pranay has shown us the counterexample $\psi = \exp{-|\mathbf{r}|}/|\mathbf{r}|^4$.
